# Cocoa Foundation Kit question - NSDecimalNumberBy...:withBehavior:

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to take a numeric value in a string and raise it by a power of 10. stumbled upon     *– decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:withBehavior:* which looks promising but I can't for the life of me figure out how to configure/set the *withBehavior* argument. I think I need to set it to *NSRoundDown* so when raising to negative power it won't round 'up' some values below a certain number of decimal places...but how does one set/use this *NSDecimalNumberBehaviors* gizmo? Sure wish Apple provided some examples in their docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`NSDecimalNumberHandler`](http://gemma.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumberHandler_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumberHandler/decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:scale:raiseOnExactness:raiseOnOverflow:raiseOnUnderflow:raiseOnDivideByZero:). It conforms to the `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` protocol, as required by the API, and allows you to configure all the behaviors you're likely to need.

Comment: Hadn't used it before so was a little "afraid" but was able to pull it off w/out a hitch! thx.